# Getting set of pdf files as a zip file from a server using python

Tags: python, pdf, server, zip

I m trying to get set of pdf files present in server as zip file using below python code. But i m not able to do so, can someone help me regarding this pls. whatever awbs i give in this code i ve to get them in one zip file.

Thanks, in advance.

```
import requests
import json

def downloadLabels(awbs):
    if awbs:
        url = 'http://<server's ip>/Labels/downloadLabels'
        resp = requests.post(url, data={'files': json.dumps(','.join(awbs))})
        print resp.json()
    else:
        print "NO AWB Provided"

downloadLabels(['1234','6789','1011'])
```

awb is a list of numbers separated by commas, using this awbs only we ll get those pdfs present in server.

Comment: What does `resp.json` returns? And it is server's job to zip the files and deliver. Although you can download files to a temp location and then zip them yourself on client side.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply, can u explain me bit more with code to download those files to a temp location pls

Answer (score 1):

**First you should try to get the binary content of each pdf**

the doc of requests in http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content give the code example:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> i = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
```

In your situtaion, You can just get the binary content through `resp.content`

**Then, you can write each pdf to an zip file**

[zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) is the standard lib to do such work. You just need created an writable Zipfile object, and write the pdfs into this Zipfile Object. I think the `writestr` function can take the file content as binary string, and will write such content into zipfile.

And code may look like this:

```
with ZipFile('zipfilename.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.writestr('nameinthezipfile', resp.content)
```